# iphone searching data from database

Tags: iphone, database

I have a excel sheet containing locations(Store name. address,city,state,zip) and I want to develop a iphone  app to search these locations using address, city, zip or using current location. Kindly tell me how can achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had a similar issue recently. I saved my excel files to csv format, and then I downloaded the code described in this link:

```
http://blog.danilocampos.com/2009/12/04/convert-a-csv-into-a-plist-file/
```

which is for a mac app that converts csv files to plist files. I had to edit the

```
- (IBAction)executeConversion:(id)sender
```

method in AppController.m to get the plist in the format I wanted, but it was straightforward. It may not be the best solution, but it was the best I could find.